# Aws cloudwatch logs send to standalone ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, amazon-eks

I have running ELK cluster on AWS EKS. I would like to send my cloudwatch logs to Elasticsearch. I tried integration in elasticsearch dashboard but I didn't understand it.
Does anyone any idea or steps to help me?

Thank you

I tried integration in elasticsearch dashboard but I didn't understant it.

Comment: It might help you ... https://medium.com/@sohit_kumar/streaming-aws-cloudwatch-logs-to-your-own-elk-logging-solution-2bbd32f25100